# Android "ant install" fails with "Install file not specified."

Tags: android

I made a project and when I run "ant install" I get the following:

> install:
>        [echo] Install file not specified.
>        [echo]
>        [echo] 'ant install' now requires the build target to be specified as well.
>        [echo]
>        [echo]
>        [echo]     ant debug install
>        [echo]     ant release install
>        [echo]     ant instrument install
>        [echo] This will build the given package and install it.
>        [echo]
>        [echo] Alternatively, you can use
>        [echo]     ant installd
>        [echo]     ant installr
>        [echo]     ant installi
>        [echo]     ant installt
>        [echo] to only install an existing package (this will not rebuild the package.)
>
> BUILD FAILED /Developer/SDKs/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:1088: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Developer/SDKs/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:1150: No message
>
> Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: Running "ant debug" first may do the trick.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As your error indicates you need to specify how you want your install to build.

If you're just doing testing using a debug build will be fine..

Try using "ant debug install" instead of just "ant install"

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SDK Tools revision 14, the `install` target doesn't not depend on a compilation target… You shall use, as specified, `ant debug install` to build and install a debug apk and so on.

** Update: **

See [the SDK Tools revision notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/tools-notes.html) and [the ant command reference on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html#AntReference)